# Access Cascaded JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js, cascading

If I have the following JSON object, how can I access the `survey.id` (e.g 1) using JavaScript? I'm using Backbone / json.stringify / object.parse

```
[{
    "class": "org.example.UserBooking",
    "id": 1,
    "booking": {
        "class": "Booking",
        "id": 1
    },
    "profile": {
        "class": "Profile",
        "id": 3
    },
    "survey": {
        "class": "Survey",
        "id": 1
    },
    "tslot": {
        "class": "TimeSlot",
        "id": 5
    }
}]
```

??

I can't figure out how to access this "survey" id as its cascaded in. If I wanted to access the "id" for example i do:

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(userbooking));

alert(obj.id);
```

thanks

---

thanks for your response. When i try the following line:

var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userbooking)); 
alert(obj.Survey.id);

i get the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined –

Comment: obj.survey.id should work based on this structure, no?

Comment: obj[0].survey.id should solve your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try accessing the id inside survey like this

```
 obj[0].survery.id
```

The json data in the current context is enclosed like this

**[ {  } ]**..

So it's a array of objects , because it's the First object we are trying to access..

It should be  **obj[0].**  and not just  **obj.**

[CHECK DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/PUycg/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use jQuery, just use `JSON.parse()`.  Then, get it using `obj.survey.id`.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(userbookingstring);
alert(obj[0].survey.id);
```

Comment: Why does he have to use `JSON.parse()`?  Seems to already be JSON?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. When i try the following line:

var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userbooking));
alert(obj.Survey.id);

i get the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive.  'obj.Survey' is not defined, 'obj.survey' is.

Comment: still i get the same error:/

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: Also, why are you using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userbooking))?  That takes an Object, converts it to a JSON string, then converts it back to and Object. That's unnecessary.

Comment: obj is an Array. you need to access the first element using: obj[0].survey.id